# Youtube API v3/ASP.NET/Google.Apis.YouTube.v3 - Many Questions (oauth, sample code, proxy)

Tags: asp.net, api, youtube, proxy

I work for a large educational institution and we used the YouTube api v2 for uploading YouTube videos to our corporate channel. We now have to implement v3 alongside other changes. I have a few questions:

**Question 1: Oauth2**

With api v2 we were able to upload directly to our YouTube channel with the credentials stored in the web.config file. But from what I understand this will no longer be possible with the use of oauth2. A popup form will ask the user to enter the credentials. Is this correct? If so, is there another method we might use, as many department will have the ability to upload videos, and for security purposes we would like to keep the channel login secret.

**Question 2: Google.Apis.YouTube.v3 nuget package Sample Code & Port number**

I downloaded the sample project at: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/dotnet , and using VS2013, is able to compile the project, but a browser windows opens (suspect it is the oath2 permissions window) complaining about a Error: redirect_uri_mismatch . From other Google searches I determined that it is because the port number changes every time I run the project and thus does not match the redirect uri set in the Google developers console. How would I go about getting the sample code to run?

**Question 3 - Proxy**

I haven't gotten so far that this might actually be a problem, but just in case it will be, I am adding this to the question list. We have a proxy server with proxy authentication. Will this be an issue (if I do finally get the sample code to run)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answers after hours of scouring websites and documentation.

Question 1:

Yes there is a method. IE Get an offline refresh token and use that to gain access. See:
[OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground)

[Generating a refresh token for YouTube API calls using the OAuth playground](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfWe1gPCnzc)

Question 2:

I was using the wrong credentials, use installed.

Question 3:

Yes it was an issue, solved it by adding this to the web.config file:

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="false" enabled="true">
  <proxy usesystemdefault="False" autoDetect="False" proxyaddress="yourproxy" />
</defaultProxy>
```